# What Jquery plugin is used in Stack Overflow help section?

Tags: discussion, javascript

I want to ask the Stack Overflow owners: what JavaScript library is used in Stack Overflow help section?

I like the animation that occurs when a part of the page is reached by scroll or just navigation to bottom of page.

I mean when you press `Start tour` button then you'll be redirected to that [page](https://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: why don't you just check the source?

Comment: because it's minified

Comment: jQuery. It is _always_ jQuery.

Comment: But can you explain what part of the help section? Do you mean the about page?

Comment: When press `Start tour` then you'll be redirected to that page

Comment: So, [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/about)?

Comment: Yes, that page, I edited my answer

Comment: @SnakeEyes answer, you say?

Comment: It's nothing more than detecting the scroll position and showing elements. No plugins involved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not a library; this is a custom implementation by the Stack Exchange team.

This approach is known as parallax web design, and usually involves moving elements in response to a user scrolling.

The animation leverages the jQuery API, but other than a few shortcuts jQuery provides, jQuery itself has nothing to do with it.

You can [see the script here](http://dev.cdn.sstatic.net/js/about.js). (I hope I didn't offend anyone by showing the script link)

Comment: Yeah, pretty much this.

Comment: You could also run it through a beautifier: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: So it's run through a minifier, but variable and function names aren't obfuscated? If you're going for bandwidth saving, you kindof need to "minify" the variables.

Comment: You know that you *can* access [the source *before* it's been minified](http://dev.cdn.sstatic.net/js/about.js)…